# Check if matrix is not Nan in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `<1x100>`. How do I check if all the values in the matrix are NaN?

Basically I want to check if the matrix only contains of NaN values with an `if-statement.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

Use the following syntax:

```
res = ~any(~isnan(X(:)));
```

if res==true it means that that the matrix contains only nan values.

**Example**

```
X = nan(3,3)
~any(~isnan(X(:)))

X(1,2) = 0;
~any(~isnan(X(:)))
```

**Results**

```
ans = 1
ans = 0
```

Comment: any(~isnan(X))  will  do the same thing. It checks if there is anything not nan

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I'd check again your edited post. I don't think it's correct.

Comment: My main issue is still there. Have you tried it? Does it really give you `true` if the matrix contains only `NaN` and `false` otherwise?

Comment: @AndrasDeak of course! I will add an example to show it

Comment: @AndrasDeak true,  a '~' operator should be added to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Lets consider x which is a vector of nan

```
x = nan(1,100);
```

to check if all the values are nan , you can do

```
if(~isempty(find(isnan(x))))
```

Comment: fantastic. Now try it with `x=[1 2 3]` . What  happens?

Comment: This is not valid MATLAB code (an `if` must have an `end`). Also, the argument of the `if` is always `true`, unless you redefine the `nan` function to return empty arrays.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have made an edit in my post i forgot to add find , now try `x = [1 2 3]` , What happens

Comment: @AnderBiguri 1)the user can add 'end' in the end thats something he has to do to complete the syntax 2) read the OP he just wants to check if all the vector is nan vector "Basically I want to check if the matrix only contains of NaN values"